# Can I use MS SQL syntax in Sybase?

Tags: sybase

I have worked on SQL Server database. Now I have to work on a Sybase database (using a Squirrel client). This query is not working :

```
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR

SELECT name
FROM   sysobjects
WHERE  type = 'U';
OPEN my_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor INTO @tableName;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        //Do something here
        FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor;
    END
CLOSE my_cursor;
DEALLOCATE CURSOR my_cursor;
```

It gives an error - `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'. 
SQLState:  ZZZZZ
ErrorCode: 156
Error occured in:
FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor INTO @table_Name`

Now this works fine in a SQL Server database (after I change the last line to `DEALLOCATE my_cursor`). Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: @Mitch Yes because all other queries work fine. This is driving me crazy!

Comment: which version of SyBase?

Comment: @Mitch Adaptive Server Enterprise/12.5.3/EBF 12156/P/ia64/HP-UX B.11.23/ase125x/1883/64-bit/FBO/Thu Nov 18 10:53:44 2004

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Mitch points out the fetch syntax is:

```
fetch cursor_name [into fetch_target_list]
```

You also need to declare the cursor in a separate batch, this means you must put a "GO" after the declare statement. You will then find that your variable drops out of scope, so you'll need to move that so that it's after the "GO".

You also need to examine @@sqlstatus to see how successful the fetch was, rather than @@FETCH_STATUS which I think is MSSQL only.

```
DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT name
  FROM   sysobjects
  WHERE  type = 'U'
go

DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(500)
set nocount on
OPEN my_cursor
FETCH my_cursor INTO @tableName

WHILE @@sqlstatus = 0
  BEGIN
      --Do something here

      FETCH my_cursor INTO @tableName
      print @tablename
  END

CLOSE my_cursor
DEALLOCATE CURSOR my_cursor
```

And no semicolons needed at the end of lines in Sybase ASE.

Comment: My Squirrel client doesn't recognize the `GO` keyword! Strange! Also why does my variable not drop out of scope when I run it on SQL server but only on SyBase?

Comment: The variable doesn't drop out of scope in MS SQL, as you don't need the GO to split it into two batches.

Comment: I've never used Squirrel, maybe there's a setting that controls it's understanding of GO. Could you try it in isql?

Comment: Don't have isql. Can't install it even as my Squirrel is launched through client's Citrix Web Server. No way for me to test. :( Will accept your answer though as it seems logical.

Comment: Can you create stored procedures? You could dump it all in a new procedure, and then run that.

Comment: it's useful for me, I just lost the keyword "GO"

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT name
  FROM   sysobjects
  WHERE  type = 'U';

OPEN my_cursor;
FETCH my_cursor INTO @tableName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
      //Do something here

      FETCH my_cursor INTO @tableName;
  END

CLOSE my_cursor;
DEALLOCATE CURSOR my_cursor;
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Now I get `Must declare variable '@table_Name'.`

Answer (score 1):

Declare `@tablename` after the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Squirrel supports `go`  as a SQL batch separator.  Go to menu item Session--> Session Properties--->  'SQL'  Tab.

Scroll to bottom and set 'Statement Separator' as 'go' (quotes not needed) .

Then follow the previous answer . The `DECLARE CUROSR` can be the only SQL statement in a batch , hence you must insert `go` after it.

In the next batch re-declare any variables that were declared in earlier batch and will be referenced in second batch.

This should work.  This is how I have been testing SQL code involving cursors for years.