# Sybase Cursor is not work in powershell script

Tags: powershell, cursor, sybase

In my work, I need to run a sql to get the objects of system and I can find one solution regarding below link: [why-is-this-query-not-working-in-sybase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138853/why-is-this-query-not-working-in-sybase), the correct SQL lists below:

```
DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name
FROM   sysobjects
WHERE  type = 'U'
go

DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(500)

OPEN my_cursor
FETCH my_cursor INTO @tableName

WHILE @@sqlstatus = 0
 BEGIN
  --Do something here
    select @tableName
  FETCH my_cursor INTO @tableName

END

CLOSE my_cursor
DEALLOCATE CURSOR my_cursor
```

Above SQL is running correctly in Sysbase, but when I write a powershell script and include above sql, the triky thing happens, I got below error:

```
******************* Exception type : System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException
 ****************** Exception message : ERROR [HY000] [MERANT][ODBC Sybase driver][SQL Server]DECLARE CURSOR must be the only statement in a query batch.
```

I searched a lot but got no result, Anyone can help me on this? thx very much.

Answer (score 0):

Probably You have to prepare a script with your SQL (for example cur.sql) and run it with isql:

```
isql -Uuser -Ppass -Sserver -Ddatabase -icur.sql
```

I hope it will useful for you.